# RN onPanResponderMove event not working after added extra lines Event method

Tags: react-native

Using PanResponder Api I can drag and drop images over the screen it works fine. But I need to catch the moment if dragged element touch a view. 
so I should make some changes on "onPanResponderMove" event,

here how it look at first:

```
 onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([ null, { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y } ]),
```

but since I need the get the moment if its touched another object I should some extra lines so I change to this;

```
onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture)=>{ 
                  //some logic
                   Animated.event([ null, { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y } ]) 
                  }
```

but after that the image not moving,  whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the Animated function like this. 

`Animated.event([ null, { dx: this.state.pan.x, dy: this.state.pan.y } ])(event, gesture)`